# Java - Can connect to mysql server in netbeans, but will not work as applet

Tags: java, mysql, windows, netbeans, applet

i'm trying to connect to a mysql server (which is on the same machine right now, as in i'm connecting to localost (I'm using Windows and have Apache, PHP, Mysql and phpmyadmin installed) yet I can connect fine to the server running the application in Netbeans, yet if I run the applet in the browser, it fails to connect, I get this error:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

Do you have any idea what could cause this? As far as I know, it's all connecting to my local machine right now. What could be the problem, the MySQL server or apache, or the java application, and how could I solve it? Thanks.

I attempted to sign the applet and I think it signed it, but it's till giving me this error though. Thanks.

Comment: I know applets don't have same access rights. Maybe you need to check in to that and enable correct access priveleges

Comment: BY default untrusted applets wont be able to do this. Google for "applet connect to database", there seem to be some pointers.

Comment: Well I have signed it, or are you on about something else?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Java enforces something similar to Javascript's Same Origin Policy: untrusted applets may only open a network connection to the server from which they were downloaded, but cross-domain access is prohibited.

To overcome this, signing the applet is required but on its own not sufficent yet for granting extended permissions, you also have to state explicitly what permissions you require. To test if it works, try granting [AllPermission](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html#AllPermission) first, you can still fine-tune this afterwards.

An easy way to grant AllPermission is by deploying the applet using [JNLP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jnlp-136707.html), add

```
<security> 
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

to your JNLP deployment descriptor.

Next, ensure that **all** Jars referenced by the applet are signed using the **same** certificate. It's not enough to sign only the applet Jar file.

In the "Java Control Panel", make sure that in "Advanced/Security" you

```
Allow user to grant permissions to signed content
```

That should solve it.

---

**A simple check to see whether signing was really successful:**

Open the Jar file with something like WinZip, go to the META-INF folder and check whether there exist two additional files next to MANIFEST.MF - one ends in .SF, the other one most probably in .RSA.